# Get the stack trace of the process from the DLL that it uses

Tags: c++11, assembly, visual-c++, dll, memory-alignment

I am working on a VC++2013 project and I am trying to get the stack trace of the calling function from the main process from a DLL attached to it. The attached DLL has `_penter` and `_pexit` defined and the main process has `/Gh` and `/GH` flags and so calls these functions. But when I try to get the stacktrace it crashes in `CaptureStackBackTrace` function. I am thinking that since the `_penter` and `_pexit` is defined in the DLL its not able to see the main processes stack. All I see is that it enters `_penter` and `_pexit` thats all. I dont see any other symbols. I might be wrong. This is the code(I used this code from the an answer from stackoverflow). This is the code to get the name of the function,

```
process = GetCurrentProcess();
SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);

frames = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, 100, stack, NULL);
symbol = (SYMBOL_INFO *)calloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 256 * sizeof(char), 1);
symbol->MaxNameLen = 255;
symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(stack[1]), 0, symbol);

printf("%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", frames - 1 - 1, symbol->Name, symbol->Address);
```

This crashes in this line `frames = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, 100, stack, NULL);` after some calls and this is the output,

```
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _penter - 0xEDB71890
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _penter - 0xEDB71890
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _penter - 0xEDB71890
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _pexit - 0xEDB718DC
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _pexit - 0xEDB718DC
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _penter - 0xEDB71890
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _penter - 0xEDB71890
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _penter - 0xEDB71890
1: printStackTrace - 0xEDB71730
1: on_enter - 0xEDB71840
1: _penter - 0xEDB71890
```

It crashed here.. and this is the crash:

`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9F8679D62 (ntdll.dll) in TraceTrack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`

Can somebody help me out in this?

EDIT:
This is my asm file,
    extern entry:Proc
    extern exitp:Proc
    PUBLIC _penter
    PUBLIC _pexit

```
.code
    PUSHREGS    macro
        push    rax
        push    rcx
        push    rdx
        push    r8
        push    r9
        push    r10
        push    r11
    endm

    POPREGS macro
        pop r11
        pop r10
        pop r9
        pop r8
        pop rdx
        pop rcx
        pop rax
    endm

_penter proc
    push rax
    lahf
    PUSHREGS
    sub rsp, 8+16
    movdqu xmmword ptr[rsp], xmm0
    sub rsp ,8
    sub  rsp,28h 
    mov  rcx,rsp
    mov  rcx,qword ptr[rcx+136]
    call entry
    add  rsp,28h
    add rsp, 8 
    movdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8+ 16
    POPREGS
    sahf
    pop rax
    ret
_penter endp

_pexit proc
    push rax
    lahf
    PUSHREGS
    sub rsp, 8+16
    movdqu xmmword ptr[rsp], xmm0
    sub rsp ,8
    sub  rsp,28h 
    mov  rcx,rsp
    mov  rcx,qword ptr[rcx+136]
    call exitp
    add  rsp,28h
    add rsp, 8 
    movdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8+ 16
    POPREGS
    sahf
    pop rax
    ret
_pexit endp

end
```

EDIT2:

Also, I tried printing the 3rd frame in the line `SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(stack[3]), 0, symbol);` and I find something strange. I find this output,

```
1:  - 0x0
1:  - 0x0
1: printStackTrace - 0xF0841750
1: printStackTrace - 0xF0841750
1:  - 0x0
1: on_enter - 0xF0841820
1:  - 0x0
1:  - 0x0
1:  - 0x0
```

The functions are organized as, (Funtion in actual program) -> _penter(exposed in DLL) -> on_enter(exposed in DLL) -> printstackFrame(exposed in DLL)

Comment: An AVE with a 0xFF...FFFF address it is typically caused by an memory alignment fault from a SIMD instruction.  In other words, your penter function is likely to misalign the stack.  Ensure that the stack pointer adjustment is a multiple of 16.  Aim for 32 is AVX code generation is likely.

Comment: @HansPassant I have added the asm file I am using. I took online help to get that going. Can you please tell me if there is something I am doing wrong there? Thanks!